# Defintiion of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

```
For S and T sets, state the definition of |S|≤|T|.
```

As simple as this should be, I am having a hard time understanding exactly what it is asking.

Comment: The last question that you asked was stated in terms of the notion $|X| \le |Y|$.  It might be a good idea to look up what it means; then maybe you could answer both questions yourself.

Comment: An answer to this question might have the form "$|S| \le |T|$ means..." or "we say $|S| \le |T|$ when..." or "$|S| \le |T|$ holds if and only if...."

Answer (score 3):

You have to write down the meaning of the mathematical statement $|S|\leq|T|$.